# How many forms of identification for job

Tags: united-states, racism

So I got hired to a fast food place and they asked for my ID, my birth certificate and my SSN card.

I thought they only need TWO forms of identification not three. They also asked if I had one in general so could this be because she thinks I’m not a citizen and she’s racist? Or because she actually need all three? I live in America btw.

Comment: Why don't you just ask her why she needs all three?

Comment: We can't tell whether a person is racist with that little detail, but what country are you in? Birth certificate sounds a little much, but maybe it's normal where you are?

Comment: I live in America. I told my mom and she said it was weird  of her to ask for the birth certificate

Comment: I an clearly missing something, why asking for documents world be racist? OP can you explain?

Comment: Well during the interview she asked if I had one. Like insinuating I don’t have one and I very obviously look Hispanic. Why would she assume I didn’t have one?

Comment: A SSN isn't a form of ID, but it is needed by employers. Or do you mean a social security card?

Comment: @jmoreno You're right that it's been within the last ~30 years that it's been common to get SSNs for children, but that's because if you don't, then you can't claim them as dependents on your tax return, get tax credits for having them, etc. OP didn't specify their citizenship, but for a native-born American citizen applying for their first job in 2020, I would be astonished if their parents hadn't already gotten them one.

Comment: It is weird to ask for a birth certificate. In the future, a passport alone is sufficient and somewhat less weird to share.

Answer (score 11):

Since you mentioned SSN (Social Security Number), I assume you’re in the United States.

When starting a job, the employer is required by the US government to submit a Form I-9, which is Employment Eligibility Verification.

You can see the documents which can be used for an I-9 on the page 3 of the form here: https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/i-9-paper-version.pdf

Note that the employer might want additional documents for some reason; I have no idea about the legality of an employer requiring documents beyond those that the I-9 requires. It’s also possible that the manager doesn’t fully understand the requirements for the I-9.

You don’t necessarily have to be a US citizen to be authorized to work. The I-9 document list mentions some which prove employment authorization (like a Social Security Card) but not identity.

Both Social Security Card and birth certificate are used to establish employment authorization, so at least for the purposes of the I-9 you wouldn’t need both.

To summarize the I-9 document requirements, you need to prove both identity and authorization to work. Some documents prove both, such as a US Passport or a Permanent Resident Card. Other documents prove only identity, like a state-issued driver’s license or ID card. Other documents prove only work authorization, like a Social Security Card or birth certificate (from some part of the US).

Comment: You might summarize those tables - an actual SSN card is only required if e.g. a state ID card is used.

Answer (score 3):

> I thought they only need TWO forms of identification not three.

What does their website say?

For the Federal I-9, this is what they need: [source](https://www.indeed.com/hire/c/info/documents-for-i-9-verification?aceid=&gclid=CjwKCAiAwrf-BRA9EiwAUWwKXmSsVtDaPM-rBw83hWUZj3osD9_DiTAm1PCmv85pI6PIkfXtBeY2exoCC7MQAvD_BwE)

For a criminal background check (if you're going to handle the cash register), they may need your SSN card as well.

> They also asked if I had one in general so could this be because she thinks I’m not a citizen and she’s racist?

Do not go through life assuming the worse about everybody.

All employers have to assume that the people applying for their jobs are not citizens. It's even a felony for them if they fill out the I-9 Federal form without checking the required documents.

Answer (score 0):

I have learned over the years to bring more forms of ID than the minimum.

I have witnessed birth certificate problems. Some people carry around a piece of paper that is the receipt from the hospital telling them how to get a birth certificate. I knew a relative who used that piece of paper for decades. They used it to start jobs, they used it at DMV. They opened bank accounts. The post office accepted it when applying for a passport. But the passport office flagged the piece of paper because it didn't have the official raised seal. It took 6 weeks to get the real birth certificate from the state.

That I-9 form has to be completed in days. If they can't see the original forms then they have to terminate your employment.

Since that incident I have known several other people who had similar problems. Their birth certificate or Social security card wasn't official. If you don't have an official one then you might have to get a replacement, or ask a parent to overnight the official one to you.

Note: the question originally used the phrase SSN. You will have to give them the number so that they can file taxes, it is just that they don't generally need to see the card to do so.